# Button element with aria-expanded not expanding when data-target has semi-colon or colon in it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

If we observe the above image data-target, aria-controls and target ID  has a semicolon in it. In the ideal case it should expand when we click on the button, as all the properties have consistent naming. But it's not working when we have a semi-colon/ colon in it. I see there is [a pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/24700) merged on the same, but it's still not working.

I have the list coming from XML and it matters for a word with and without semi-colon and it makes a lot of difference in my case. Is there a way I can escape it in the ID?

I am expecting the data target should expand and collapse based on the aria-controls.

[image]

```
 <button tabindex='0' role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark m-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#vsn-{{vs_feat_name[1:]|replace(':', 'colon')}}-end" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#vsn-{{vs_feat_name[1:]|replace(':', 'colon')}}-end">
                <span style="font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;">{{ vs_feat_name+' ('+vs_val['count']|string+')' }}</span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse" id="vsn-{{vs_feat_name[1:]|replace(':', 'colon')}}-end">
                <div class="card border border-dark" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 1rem">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <p>
                      Frames containing <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">{{vs_feat_name}}: </span>{{ vs_val['vn_class_mem']|length }}<br>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card card-body">
                    <h5>
                      {% for vn_mem in vs_val['vn_class_mem'] %}
                      <button tabindex='0' role="button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark m-1" data-toggle="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'render_vn_class', vn_class_id=vn_mem) }}';">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase;">{{ vn_mem }}</span>
                      </button>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs code, not an image of code.

Comment: If you are dynamically generating the HTML, why not just create IDs that don't have those characters? You can still use the original value that are you already using, just remove the colons.